# HTTP error 500 when trying to go to localhost/phpmyadmin on centos 8

Tags: http-error, http-status-code-500

when I'm trying to go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` then I'm getting HTTP error 500.i have installed PHP, PHP-MySQL, MySQL,apache...please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: also showing this ///This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500///

Comment: please edit your question and say exact error text.

Answer (score 1):

Check your log
if you have this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCookie() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:217
```

Try to install **php-json** package

I hope this can be useful.